# Bootstrap - Navbar with Image

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I want to achieve the following design, but it has to be responsive (I am using bootstrap):

[image]

I used the following HTML5 tags

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="logo visible-md visible-xs visible-sm visible-lg col-md-2  col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
        <img src="/images/logo.png">
    </div>
    <div class="pull-right">
        <img src="/images/Banner.png" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
<br>

    <div id="nav" class="navbar" style="width:90%">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">test dp</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The problem is when re-sizing the browser (i.e. opening from mobile device or re-sizing the browser size ), the image Banner.png change place and is not aligned anymore with the blue navbar

Edit 1:
I have used Absolute Positioning and added the code here, it works fine but is not stable (i.e. produces the space between the image and the navbar is not the same when I resize the browser with different sizes) 
https://jsfiddle.net/c45xqLe9/

Comment: Because the Banner.png has the `img-responsive` class on it it will have a smaller height at smaller screen sizes making it mis-align with your blue bar. You could try anchoring it with a `position:absolute;` maybe

Comment: How shall I fix it ? as if i remove it, the image keeps the same size but still is not aligned with the blue nav bar .. the image is half above the navbar and half below the navbar

Comment: If you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demoing the problem then I or some else might be able to help you

Comment: FYI you can use http://placehold.it/ followed by the dimensions for your images. ex: `<img src="http://placehold.it/100x150" class="img-responsive">` 100x150 being the width and height

Comment: I will add it on fiddle now

Comment: here is the fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/c45xqLe9/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101340/discussion-between-kasparov92-and-zgood).